# Why does the service worker download a page instead of navigating to it?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I've got a strange scenario with a service worker where instead of navigating to a page it will download a page instead of navigating to it.

On the link that it's supposed to navigate to there's nothing special, it's an anchor tag with an `href` attribute pointing to a sign out URL.

The relevant part of the service worker follows:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
        // this part I added to circumvent the issue
        if (event.request.url.match(/SignOut/)) {
            return false;
        }
        event.respondWith(
            (async () => {
                try {
                    const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
                    return networkResponse;
                } catch (error) {
                    // This section is irrelevant, I've confirmed it doesn't run when the error happens
                }
            })()
        );
    }
});
```

I couldn't find any information on why the browser would download the page instead of navigating to it, but it only happens when the service worker processes the `/SignOut/` URL, and only on that URL that I have noticed. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide the raw response of the `/SignOut` request?